# End-User AD Management solution

Tags: active-directory, user-management, delegation

We've just migrated to a pure Microsoft environment and are looking for an end-user AD management solution.

Ideally we'd like users to be able to manage their personal info in AD. We have ~500 users in our domain.

I've found a few products from google searches, but I'd be interested to hear what others may be using.

Answer (score 1):

We've got about 85% of the infrastructure in place to build our own web-portal to do just that. It hooks into our identity management system, so their personal information is changed in not just AD, but the ERP/HR systems as well.

The tricky part is creating the transaction processor behind the web page. PowerShell is great for that, but straight up LDAP can do for a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I have setup a system similar to what you are talking about in the past with Apache+PHP+[adLdap](http://adldap.sourceforge.net/).  While I have nothing to share -- its fairly simple to create a display of a list of given parameters, and push them back in via PHP.  If you are at all familiar with PHP and LDAP it shouldn't take more than half a day to a day to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Quest ActiveRoles is a nice product. It'll also let you completely handle provisioning users and groups, ensuring that everything follows your rigorous standards. It has a fully functional web application for end user self-service as well. The catch is it's rather pricey.